# Where is the javascript HTMLElement.style.property=value syntax specified?

Tags: javascript, css, properties, styles

I'm having a little trouble finding the specification for the syntax

```
HTMLElement.style.property=”value” // set the property value
```

I see this syntax frequently used (and have used it myself successfully) but cannot find a specification that allows this syntax.

An example of the use of this syntax is at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp  and at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style but I cannot seem to find the syntax in the CSSOM specification: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/

The CSSOM specifies an HTMLElement interface of

```
HTMLElement implements ElementCSSInlineStyle;
```

where `ElementCSSInlineStyle` is

```
 [NoInterfaceObject]
 interface ElementCSSInlineStyle {
     [SameObject, PutForwards=cssText] readonly attribute CSSStyleDeclaration style;
 };
```

and where `CSSStyleDaeclaration` is

```
 interface CSSStyleDeclaration {
     attribute DOMString cssText;
     readonly attribute unsigned long length;
     getter DOMString item(unsigned long index);
     DOMString getPropertyValue(DOMString property);
     DOMString getPropertyPriority(DOMString property);
     void setProperty(DOMString property, [TreatNullAs=EmptyString] DOMString value, [TreatNullAs=EmptyString] optional DOMString priority = "");
     void setPropertyValue(DOMString property, [TreatNullAs=EmptyString] DOMString value);
     void setPropertyPriority(DOMString property, [TreatNullAs=EmptyString] DOMString priority);
     DOMString removeProperty(DOMString property);
     readonly attribute CSSRule? parentRule;
     attribute DOMString cssFloat;
 };
```

Maybe I'm missing something fundamental but it doesn't look to me if the syntax in question is allowed by the specification. If anyone has a reference to the syntax that allows the direct setting of a style property I'd appreciate receiving it.

Comment: You're looking at the DOM interface spec, not the syntax spec. What *specifically* are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed in the CSSOM spec for the `CSSStyleDeclaration`, right under the [`cssFloat` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-cssfloat):

> For each CSS property property that is a [supported CSS
>   property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#supported-css-property), the
>   following partial interface applies where camel-cased attribute is
>   obtained by running the [CSS property to IDL
>   attribute](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#css-property-to-idl-attribute)
>   algorithm for property.
>
> ```
> partial interface CSSStyleDeclaration {
>            attribute DOMString _camel-cased attribute;
> };
> ```
>
> The `camel-cased attribute` attribute, on getting, must return the
>   result of invoking
>   [getPropertyValue()](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-getpropertyvalue)
>   with the argument being the result of running the [IDL attribute to
>   CSS
>   property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#idl-attribute-to-css-property)
>   algorithm for camel-cased attribute.
>
> Setting the `camel-cased attribute` attribute must invoke
>   [setProperty()](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setproperty)
>   with the first argument being the result of running the [IDL attribute
>   to CSS
>   property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#idl-attribute-to-css-property)
>   algorithm for camel-cased attribute, as second argument the given
>   value, and no third argument. Any exceptions thrown must be re-thrown.

That way, they worked around declaring each single supported property as an own IDL attribute.

Comment: Thanks Bergi; I just missed it. I thought it was something simple.